# What is a terminal value problem, how does it relate to the initial value problem, and which methods are used to solve them?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

The title summarizes my question(s):

- What is a terminal value problem?
- How does it relate to the initial value problem?
- Which methods are used to solve them?
- Can I somehow transform them into an IVP and solve them using e.g. RK4?
- For ordinary differential equations, is the terminal value problem equivalent to solving an initial value problem with negative time? (For example in a spatial domain, the question of an IVP is given a point particle at position X at time T0, find where the particle will be at time T0+T. Logically the question of a TVP would be given a point particle at position X at time T0+T, find where the particle originally was at time T0?)

I have spent time researching the topic online, but they only appear in (mostly Arxiv) research papers which are very hard to follow without a mathematics background. I am writing a C++ library for numeric evaluation of ordinary differential equations, and would like to be as complete as possible, which is the reason for this query.

Comment: In the setting of ODEs, it is just an IVP with the time interval of interest being before the point where you initialize, so you just move backward in time.

Comment: In optimal control, one usually gets a terminal value problem for the dual function. However, this is coupled to the primal, so that overall a boundary value problem results.